# Angular 2 routing: Great Grandchildren

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

While nesting child routes I am running into the `cannot match any routes` error on my great-grandchildren routes.

Routes to children:

```
const appRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/one',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'one',
    component: OneComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'two',
    component: TwoComponent,
  },
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Routes to grandchildren:

```
const oneRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'one',
    component: OneComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'a',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
       { path: 'a', component: AComponent },
       { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
    ],
  },
];
export const oneRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(oneRoutes);
```

Routes to great grandchildren:

```
const aRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'sub-one',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
       { path: 'sub-one', component: SubOneComponent },
       { path: 'sub-two', component: SubTwoComponent },
    ],
  },
];

export const aRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(aRoutes);
```

The child `OneModule` is importing the `AModule` and `oneRouting`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule, oneRouting, AModule ],
  declarations: [ OneComponent, BComponent ],
  exports: [ OneComponent ]
})
export class OneModule {}
```

and grandchild `AModule` is importing `aRouting`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule, aRouting ],
  declarations: [ AComponent, SubOneComponent, SubTwoComponent ],
  exports: [ AComponent ]
})
export class AModule {}
```

A funny thing I notice: when the app starts it navigates to the default child route `one`, but not to grandchild route `a`.  If I navigate to route `two` and then back to `one` it finds default route `a`.

Why doesn't Angular2 see those great grandchildren routes?

[link to plunk...](http://plnkr.co/edit/qvMwbYWdiBCjnStfsC5l?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Routing works if I combine the all the grandchild routes into a single router:

```
const oneRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'one',
    component: OneComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'a',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
       { 
         path: 'a', 
         component: AComponent, 
         children: [
            {
              path: '',
              redirectTo: 'sub-one',
              pathMatch: 'full',
            },
             { path: 'sub-one', component: SubOneComponent },
             { path: 'sub-two', component: SubTwoComponent },

           ],
       },
       { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

[revised plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wbwf31tqArdjdVcX3HDn?p=preview)

So what I am trying to determine is if we are limited to having these child route modules one-deep off the main one, or if my initial implementation was off.

**UPDATE**

As Robin suggested, using the Lazy Loading pattern allows the routes to be nested. [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XsnwUPD7JMGjMeGZlsGL?p=preview) for anyone who is interested.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at this. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#lazy-loading-route-configuration

Comment: @Robin I believe the section you targeted is for lazy loading, which is not what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yes, but it will prevent these problems since every module is responsible for each own routing

Comment: @Robin.  That worked. Thanks.